# How to dispatch multiple action creators (React + Redux + Server-side rendering)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I've been following a great course on how to build a server-side rendered app with React and Redux, but I'm now in a situation that the course doesn't cover and I can't figure out by myself.

Please consider the following component (it's pretty basic, except for the export part at the bottom):

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {       
        this.props.fetchHomePageData();
    }   

    handleLoadMoreClick() {
        this.props.fetchNextHomePagePosts();
    }   

    render() {

        const posts = this.props.posts.homepagePosts; 
        const featuredProject = this.props.posts.featuredProject; 
        const featuredNews = this.props.posts.featuredNews; 
        const banner = this.props.posts.banner; 
        const data = ( posts && featuredProject && featuredNews && banner ); 

        if( data == undefined ) {
            return <Loading />; 
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <FeaturedProject featuredProject={ featuredProject } />
                <FeaturedNews featuredNews={ featuredNews } />
                <Banner banner={ banner } />                
                <PostsList posts={ posts } heading="Recently on FotoRoom" hasSelect={ true } />
                <LoadMoreBtn onClick={ this.handleLoadMoreClick.bind( this ) } />               
            </div>
        ); 

    }

}

function mapStateToProps( { posts } ) {
    return { posts }
}

export default {
    component: connect( mapStateToProps, { fetchHomePageData, fetchNextHomePagePosts } )( HomePage ),
    loadData: ( { dispatch } ) => dispatch( fetchHomePageData() )
};
```

The above works fine: the loadData function makes an API request to fetch some data, which is fed into the component through the mapStateToProps function. But what if I wanted to fire multiple action creators in that same loadData function? The only thing that kind of works is if I write the function like this:

```
function loadData( store ) {
    store.dispatch( fetchFeaturedNews() );
    return store.dispatch( fetchHomePageData() );
}

export default {
    component: connect( mapStateToProps, { fetchHomePageData, fetchNextHomePagePosts } )( HomePage ),
    loadData: loadData
};
```

but this is not great because I need all data to be returned... Keep in mind that the exported Component ends up in the following route configuration:

```
const Routes = [
    {
        ...App, 
        routes: [
            {
                ...HomePage, // Here it is!
                path: '/', 
                exact: true
            },
            {
                ...LoginPage, 
                path: '/login'
            },              
            {
                ...SinglePostPage, 
                path: '/:slug'
            },
            {
                ...ArchivePage, 
                path: '/tag/:tag'
            },                                      
        ]
    }
];
```

and here's how the loadData function is used once the component is needed by a certain route:

```
app.get( '*', ( req, res ) => {

    const store = createStore( req ); 

    const fetchedAuthCookie = req.universalCookies.get( authCookie ); 

    const promises = matchRoutes( Routes, req.path ).map( ( { route } ) => {
        return route.loadData ? route.loadData( store, req.path, fetchedAuthCookie ) : null;
    }).map( promise => {
        if( promise ) {
            return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                promise.then( resolve ).catch( resolve ); 
            }); 
        }
    });

    ...

}
```

Also, here's an example of the actions fired by the action creators. They all return promises:

```
export const fetchHomePageData = () => async ( dispatch, getState, api ) => {

    const posts = await api.get( allPostsEP );

    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_POSTS_LIST', 
        payload: posts
    });             

}
```

and the reducer:

```
export default ( state = {}, action ) => {
    switch( action.type ) {
        case 'FETCH_POSTS_LIST':
            return {
                ...state, 
                homepagePosts: action.payload.data 
            }                                       
        default: 
            return state; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something but can't you just return the Array? could you show how you `loadData` function is later used?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk Hi, I've updated my answer. Thanks for looking!

Comment: @grazianodev can you explain this *but this is not great because I need all data to be returned*? what do you mean by "data to be returned"?

Comment: @MayankShukla Well, right now the loadData function only returns the data fetched by `fetchHomePageData()`; what I want is for the loadData function to return both that and the data fetched by `fetchFeaturedNews()`. In other words, I want it to return two sets of data rather than just one, so that they can both be mapped over in the `app.get( ... )` function that is at the very bottom of my question. Combining them into an array like @TomasMularczyk suggested sounds nice, but I can't seem to make it work...

Comment: Could show implementation of fetch... does they return Promise?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk Yes, they all return promises. I've updated my answer with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your actions return a Promise, and you are asking how can you return more than one Promise. Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
function loadData({ dispatch }) {
  return Promise.all([
    dispatch( fetchFeaturedNews() ),
    dispatch( fetchHomePageData() ),
  ]);
}
```

But... remember that Promise.all will resolve when all of it's Promises resolve, and it will return an **Array** of values:

```
function loadData({ dispatch }) {
  return Promise.all([
    dispatch( fetchFeaturedNews() ),
    dispatch( fetchHomePageData() ),
  ]).then(listOfResults => {
    console.log(Array.isArray(listOfResults)); // "true"
    console.log(listOfResults.length); // 2
  });
}
```

So you will probably want to handle it differently.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you. But how would this be handled in the mapStatetoProps function, I'm only getting the result of the second request.